# How do I to pass two variables to a python function and get two variables returned?

Tags: python

what is the simplest way to pass two variables to a function in Python and get two variables back from the function

thanks in advance.

Comment: @ninja `fnct(a, b): return c, d`. `x, y = fnct(a, b)`

Comment: see official faq docs https://docs.python.org/2.7/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference

Answer (score 2):

You write a function that takes 2 inputs, and return a comma separated list of outputs:

```
def function(first, second):
    return first, second

firstOutput, secondOutput = function(1,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a definition that takes 2 values as an input, and have a return below that that returns 2 values.

For example:

```
#Create a definition 
def HelloWorld(valueA, valueB):
    print(valueA)
    print(valueB) 
    return 'Hello', 'World'


# Call the definition 
HelloWorld('HelloA', 'HelloB')
```

Comment: Python supports returning multiple values

Comment: Tested it, and you are right.